# With some theory prove that A⊂Cl(Int(ClA))

Tags: general-topology

A⊂Cl(Int(ClA))

Yes or No?
Counter-Example: A=Q, IntQ = ∅, ClQ = R,
Cl(Int(Cl(Q))) = Cl(Int(R)) = ClR = R ⊃ Q

But what about complete proof??

And second one: A⊃Int(Cl(IntA))

Comment: Your counterexample is a complete proof.

Comment: @preferred_anon OP's "counterexample" isn't a counterexample. It is an example of the claim working correctly.

Comment: @DonThousand Oh yeah whoops. Retracted.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Let $A$ be the Cantor set.

Hence, $Cl(A)=A$, and $Int(Cl(A))=\varnothing$, so $Cl(Int(Cl(A)))=\varnothing$.

Let $B$ be the complement of the Cantor set in $(0,1)$.

Thus, $B$ is open, and so, $Cl(Int(B))=(0,1)$ since it is dense, and so $Int(Cl(Int(B)))=(0,1)$, which is a contradiction to the second claim.

Comment: but what about proof without examples, only topological transformations

Comment: First, your counterexample is not valid. Second, disproving a claim is done by counterexample. This is a proof. You don't need anything else.

Comment: ok, and something except from cantor set, please?

Comment: What is the issue with the Cantor set? Any counterexample is going to be weird no matter what.

Comment: because i have never heard of cantor set, it can be easier to understand when example is like Q,R,Z,N etc

Comment: There aren't any good examples with those..

Comment: nowhere dense set, btw?

Comment: A simpler example for the first question: In the space of real numbers, let $A$ be a set consisting of just one point. For the second, let $A$ consist of all but one point.